# TP Link router internet connection issue

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have a TPLink router and broadband internet connection. It works fine normally but after power failure(power coming again) and internet connection issue arise. No internet connection in my router through the WAN port. After 5/10 minutes random trying of putting the connector to the WAN port it works.

First time i thought ISP problem and asked them but no issue found, cause direct connection on my computer working perfectly but in router not.

Then I back to TPLink service center and after a week they give me a new router with same brand. But still not working and showing same behavior.

Any solution please!!

Comment: That sounds like an ISP issue. Do you have DSL internet? It could be failing (or taking a long time) to sync correctly.

Comment: So, what it the probable solution as ISP person are not good enough to find out. @DavidPostill

Comment: *shrug*. 1/ Use a different ISP that knows what they are doing, or 2/ Buy a UPS, or 3/ Put up with it.

Comment: First thing , please check your connectivity using a laptop or pc .If its connect properly or not .In this method you can identify whether your router or the connectivity is faulty. Secondly , please check TPLink website if there is any firmware up gradation available for this production .Sometimes a firmware upgrade can solve the issue . Please also check whether it's possible to use a LAN port as WAN port or not ? Generally cheap routers doesn't have this capability.

Comment: Direct connection with laptop works fine and there is no update firmware available now. Also  LAN port as WAN port not possible here.